Start systemd service only after gnome automount has completed
I have a systemd service that requires usb devices to be auto-mounted before it runs.
My usb devices are auto-mounted in /media/my_username/
I currently use a sleep 10 + auto-login, but in rare cases, the automount only completes after that. So when I ls /media/my_username/, I get an empty directory.
I tried using RequiresMountsFor=/media/my_username/ but it didnt work.
I saw many solutions using fstab but in my case, I don't know which device will (or will not) be plugged in.
I also tried using Requires=local-fs.target and After=local-fs.target without success.

You should really pull the service with the mount (WantedBy= it) and not e.g. multi-users.target.

Thanks Tom. How would I which mount to use? I know the mount parent directory, but I can't tell if the mount point is going to be /media/my_username/random_drive_1 or /media/my_username/random_drive_x

So how does it "requires usb devices to be auto-mounted before it runs" when it's / they're "random drive(s)"? I'm not seeing the sense here to be frank. Can you give a bit more context on this?

Here is the context:
If a file named x.txt is contained on any usb drive at boot, I want to do action A. If no usb drive contain a file called x.txt, i want to do action B. I can't access this computer except for this usb port, so I need an external way to chose between A or B.
Currently, if the auto-mount isn't completed when, action B isn't launched, even if a usb drive containing x.txt has been plugged in.

I don't think it's possible, at least not with systemd. The best/closest thing I can think of is the ConditionPathExists= directive. The thing is, "auto mount" you mentioned isn't even part of system boot process, but handled by udisks after your DE started (i.e. logged in via a DM), which means even if you order it after a user manager, you can't guarantee the timing to check the file is correct. What I could think of is either you do have some ugly "sleep n seconds and check if some file exists" in a script (and create service that runs the script and wanted by some user@xxxx.service).

Or, you "focus on" a specific mount point (e.g. check for a specific filesystem label, which is normally used by udisks as the name of the mountpoint directory when set).
